# Admob (Ads) not displaying after app goes live

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I am having application in which i had implemented ad mob for ads.

Ads are displaying properly when i was working on it and test it on my simulator and real device.

Here is the image when i was testing app.

I am having latest version of admob implemented 7.27.0

[image: At the time of testing on device and simulator]

so that after all done when i upload this app on app store and now this app is live but it will not displaying any ads. I have implemented both banner as well as interstitial but no any ads are displaying.

[image: After Release on AppStore(live app)]

Answer (score 1):

Implement the GADBannerView programmatically.

Comment: How do you know Tejas Patel hasn't done this already? And even if he didn't: why would it make any difference? Please better describe your solution and why it works. At the moment, this isn't an answer but rather a comment.

Comment: Is it live on AppStore?

Comment: Yes its live on app store

Comment: Did you find a solution?